# Сортировка по строкам в классе

Tags: c++, сортировка

Создается массив объектов класса, в каждом несколько полей со строками, (1)нужно дать пользователю выбрать по какому полю он желает произвести сортировку(по какому принципу будет происходить, не важно). Сделал пробно только по одному полю, но не сортирует. (2) Еще один вопрос, уже давно пытаюсь понять, как в классах использовать char(как раз закомментировал метод, там данные нужны в виде char), ибо не понимаю как правильно делать запись, подскажите пожалуйста(Отметил, как делаю в коде ). Есть вариант каждый символ копировать, но думаю есть быстрее способ.

```
    class Mobile {
    public:
        string name; // Например  char *name = new char[30]. В конструкторе strncpy(this->name, name, 30 )
        string date;  
        int number; 
        string address;

        Mobile() {};
        Mobile(string nam, string de, int num, string address) {
            name = nam;
            date = de;
            number = num;
            this->address = address;
        }
        string Raddress() {
            return address;
        }
    };

    bool comp(Mobile& s1, Mobile& s2) {
        return s1.address > s2.address;
    }
        /*  Еще есть вот такой вариант, но не пробовал, потому что не знаю как передать параметры в sort
        Ну и еще данные в виде char    
        bool comp(Mobile *s1, Mobile* s2) {
                return ( strcmp(s1->name, s2->name) < 0 ) ? true : false;
            }
        */

    int main()
    {
        list<Mobile> List;
        Mobile abonent[3];

        abonent[0] = Mobile("Q", "w", 13, "egw");
        abonent[1] = Mobile("qqwe", "gggge", 13, "qwertyy");
        abonent[2] = Mobile("qwerweefgr", "qewfewwe", 15, "q");

        List.sort(comp);
        cout << "Сортировка" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Ну, конечно не сортирует. У вас отдельно массив, и отдельно пустой список, который вы зачем-то сортируете. Вам нужно сортировать массив: `sort(abonent, abonent+3, comp);` Еще, даже если ваш компилятор на это не ругается, параметры `comp` лучше сделать константными ссылками.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сделал как вы написали, но все равно не получилось

Comment: Покажите новый код.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat простите, и в правду работает, просто изменил строки, которые передавал и результат стал виден. Спасибо